# Caching for .NET (not in websites)

Tags: .net, windows-services

I need a cache that responds to memory pressure like the one build-into ASP.NET. I'm not using a web site, however, I'm building a Windows Service.

Any suggestions? (code, techniques, products, I don't care as long as it's in-memory)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're familiar with the ASP.NET Cache (`System.Web.Caching`), you can still reference and use it, even if you're not running within a web application.

Comment: You can access it via System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache (static property)

Comment: Man that is non-obvious. I tried to use it today and both "HttpContext.Current.Cache" and "New Cache" were failing without telling me why. Of course the non-obvious HttpRuntime.Cache worked like a champ.

Comment: Agreed.  But HttpContext.Current will always be null if you're not processing an ASP.NET request.

Comment: .Net 4.0 has "object caching" now so you don't have to rely on the System.Web library version. See http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/object-caching----net-4/37

Answer (score 2):

- [Caching Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203226.aspx) from Microsoft Paterns & Practices.
- Project [Velocity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/cc655792.aspx) from Microsoft.

Comment: Velocity is an out-of-process option. That makes it great for server farms, but silly for an application that will one have one running instance world-wide.

Comment: I listed it as an option so that you are at least aware of your otions. It is up to you to evaluate and eliminate based on your requirements, cost-benefit analysis, and thought process. After all, it is hard to determine what's silly or not about an application given just a couple of sentences. Also keep in mind, it is out-of-process but in memory. It may be nice to find things already cached in memory when your application starts up.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the Microsoft Enterprise library Caching Block:

*"Nearly every application needs to cache data. While you're probably familiar wth the caching functionality built into ASP.NET, the Enterprise Library Caching Block provides in-memory, file-based, or database caching storage for all your other .NET applications. "*

[Caching App Block](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/leon.pereira/ELCachingApplBlock07142005063621AM/ELCachingApplBlock.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[memcached](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/) has clients for .Net:

- [enyim.com Memcached Client](http://www.codeplex.com/EnyimMemcached)
- [memcached Providers](http://www.codeplex.com/memcachedproviders) (for ASP.NEt cache).